# C++ Find element in list of tuples using predicate

Tags: c++, stl, tuples, tr1, template-meta-programming

I have a `stl::list` of tuples which I want to search for element using `std::find_if` using multiple type comparison in each. Can I associate a tuple type with a specific templated `get()` function? So there will be no need to pass field number to a predicate template.

I created a predicate like this:

```
template<typename T, size_t field>
struct obj_predicate : public std::unary_function<ObjectRecordType, bool>
{
    const T* comparisonObject;
    obj_predicate(const T& cObj) : comparisonObject(&cObj) {}
    bool operator()(const ObjectRecordType& obj) const
    {
        return *comparisonObject == std::tr1::get<field>(obj);
    }
};
```

What I want is like `obj_predicate<int>(3)` aware of a position of `int` in tuple.

Comment: Not really but if You know a solution why not.

Comment: What don't you like about your current implementation?

Comment: I have a factory which create instances by values of different types. This design obligates me to overload `createInstance` method and call find_if with different field number and value of course (which could be declared with template typename in `createInstance`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use a "loop". This will return the *last* index matching the element with the given type.

```
template <typename T, typename S, int i = std::tr1::tuple_size<T>::value - 1>
struct tuple_index
{
    enum
    {
        value = std::tr1::is_same<typename std::tr1::tuple_element<i, T>::type, S>::value ?
            i :
            tuple_index<T, S, i-1>::value
    };
};

template <typename T, typename S>
struct tuple_index<T, S, -1>
{
    enum { value = -1 };
};
```

[Example:](http://ideone.com/AL0Q4)

```
printf("%d\n", tuple_index<std::tr1::tuple<int, double>, int>::value);    // 0
printf("%d\n", tuple_index<std::tr1::tuple<int, double>, double>::value); // 1
printf("%d\n", tuple_index<std::tr1::tuple<int, double>, long>::value);   // -1
```